The connection was reset error with firebase firestore database using laravel
I'm following this guide: https://medium.com/@moizali1011/mastering-firestore-crud-operations-in-laravel-a-comprehensive-guide-1e4f2f7bb28f.
I installed all the package associated with it, that includes https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#windows.
I'm running this using XAMPP in

Windows 11
PHP v8.1
Laravel v10

Code below:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Laravel\Firebase\Facades\Firebase;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

class FirebaseController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        $database = app('firebase.firestore')->database();
        $database1 = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('test');
        $database2 = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('test')->document(1);

        //this prints
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($database);
        print_r($database1);
        print_r($database2);

        //this causes the error and any other attempts to perform CRUD
        $documents = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('test')->documents();
    }
}

current rules:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}

I also tried to allow all just in case that was the cause but I still got the same error
Output of the print_r above in order
Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient Object
(
    [connection:Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient:private] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc Object
        (
            [serializer] => Google\ApiCore\Serializer
            [firestore] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\V1\FirestoreClient
            [resourcePrefixHeader] => projects/myproject/databases/(default)
            [databaseRoutingHeader] => project_id=myproject&database_id=(default)
            [isUsingEmulator] => 
        )

    [database:Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient:private] => (default)
    [valueMapper:Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient:private] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\ValueMapper Object
        (
            [connection] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc
            [returnInt64AsObject] => 
        )

    [projectId:Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient:private] => myproject
)
Google\Cloud\Firestore\CollectionReference Object
(
    [connection] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc
    [valueMapper] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\ValueMapper Object
        (
            [connection] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc
            [returnInt64AsObject] => 
        )

    [name] => projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/test
    [parent] => 
)
Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentReference Object
(
    [connection] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc
    [valueMapper] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\ValueMapper Object
        (
            [connection] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc
            [returnInt64AsObject] => 
        )

    [parent] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\CollectionReference Object
        (
            [connection] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc
            [valueMapper] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\ValueMapper Object
                (
                    [connection] => Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc
                    [returnInt64AsObject] => 
                )

            [name] => projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/test
            [parent] => 
        )

    [name] => projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/test/1
)


NOTE: checking the usage graph it shows they returned something and I was able to fetch it once but after a refresh it goes with that error again
